# Link-time optimization: What is "type merging"

Tags: c++, gcc, one-definition-rule, link-time-optimization

On [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-5/changes.html) page GCC 5 lists the following under Link-time optimization improvements:

> One Definition Rule based merging of C++ types has been implemented. Type merging enables better devirtualization and alias analysis.

What is C++ type merging and how is it related to the ODR?